# How to remove all dynamically created elements with a button

Tags: javascript, html

**I am trying to figure out a challenge here  so may i ask if what could be the error I made
because it keeps saying

ERROR FOUND

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null     at eeset (script.js:13)     at `HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index2.html:20) eeset @ script.js:13 onclick @ index2.html:20 ** newbie here
```

The details are here :

```js
function ageInDays() {
        var birthYear =prompt('What year were you born.... Good Friend?');
        var agemoto = (2018 - birthYear) * 365;
        var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        var textAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + agemoto + ' days old');
        h1.setAttribute('id', 'agemoto');
        h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
        document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
        
    }
        
    function eeset() {
        document.getElementById('ageInDays').remove();
    }
```

```css
    .container-1 {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .flex-box-container-1 {
        display: flex;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    .flex-box-container-1 div{
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
        <title>Javasript on Steroids</title>
       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-1">
            <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days</h2>
    
             <div class="flex-box-container-1">
                <div>
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click me</button>
                </div>
    
                <div>
                     <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eeset()">Reset</button>
                 </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="flex-box-container-1">
                <div id="flex-box-result"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I highly appreciate any kind of help to Thank you!!

Comment: There is no DOM object with id `ageInDays`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit the question to include an indicative title relevant to your issue.

Comment: You have no element with ID "ageInDays" in your html. Therefore `getElementById('ageInDays')` returns `null` and `null.remove();` gives you the error.

Comment: You should change the title of your question for more clearance and visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `querySelectorAll` method to remove all your `agemoto` id `attribute` when you click on `reset` button

Since you are loading the id `agemoto` dynamically so we need to make sure that we remove all the results matching with that id.

For this we need to use `forEach` method `querySelectorAll` to remove call elements from the DOM.

```
function eeset() {
 document.querySelectorAll('#agemoto').forEach(e => 
 e.parentNode.removeChild(e)); //Remove All results
}
```

**Live Demo**

```js
function ageInDays() {
  var birthYear = prompt('What year were you born.... Good Friend?');
  var agemoto = (2018 - birthYear) * 365;
  var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  var textAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + agemoto + ' days old');
  h1.setAttribute('id', 'agemoto');
  h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
  document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);

}

function eeset() {
  document.querySelectorAll('#agemoto').forEach(e => e.parentNode.removeChild(e));
}
```

```css
.container-1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-box-container-1 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-box-container-1 div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
  <title>Javasript on Steroids</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-1">
    <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days</h2>

    <div class="flex-box-container-1">
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click me</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eeset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-box-container-1">
      <div id="flex-box-result"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling

```
document.getElementById('ageInDays').remove()
```

But there is no HTML element with that ID. I think you wanted to get this one

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click me</button>
```

In which case you need to add an ID attribute, like

```
 <button id="ageInDays" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click me</button>
```

Then the same js should work

Answer (score 1):

Watever element you are trying to remove in eeset() needs to have id as ‘ageInDays’

So assuming h1 set attribute should have been ‘ageInDays’ instead of ‘ageMoto’